# Question about $p$-adic exponential

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $K$ a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ and $S=p^N\mathcal O_K$ where $\mathcal O_K$ the ring of integers of $K.$ I know that for $N>>0$ enough large the $p$-adic exponential  $\exp_p$ converge on $S,$ so my question is  : 
it is true that $\exp_p(S)\subset \mathcal O_K^*$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Of course: look at the series expansion for the exponential and check every term aside from the constant term will be in the maximal ideal.

Comment: thank you @KCd, can you clarify a bit more.

Comment: The exponential is a power series. Look at each term besides the constant term and check it has absolute value less than 1. (Have you done that?) And $\exp(s)$ is a limit of partial sums, each of which is congruent to 1 modulo the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_K$, so the limit has this property too.

Comment: @KCd, sorry! but I don't understand your method, How I can prove that $|\exp_p(s)|=1$ for $s\in S$?

Comment: If $y = 1 + a + b + c$ and $|a|$, $|b|$, and $|c|$ are all less than 1 then $|y| = 1$. Prove every term in the exponential series besides the constant term has absolute value less than 1 when it is evaluated at a point in the disc of convergence.